# I would like to know if I can run a 60 amp sub panel, off a 100amp sub panel, while traveling 315'?

Tags: electrical

Am I able to run a 60 amp sub panel off a 100 sub panel, while traveling 315'?

Comment: It depends. How fast are you traveling and how fast is the panel running?

Comment: Simple answer is yes, but it will probably depend on the electrical loads already on the main and sub panel/s.

Comment: Length of wire accumulates resistance. Resistance can be mitigated by using larger wire. The increase in size would need to be calculated based on your acceptable voltage loss, actual load, and local regs (particularly if Canadian). A load calc would also likely need to be done to determine if it would be permitted.

Comment: Your 100 amp panel can be provisioned for 80 A of calculated loads (not breakers added up, which is often much more.) Your 60A panel can be provisioned for 48A of calculated loads, which leaves only 32A of calculated loads at your 100A panel if the 60A is fully loaded. If you have 60A of loads, you need an 80A subpanel, leaving only 20A for other loads at the 100A panel. Depending on the calculated loads you may need upgrades to the sub-panel feed and/or service feed. Other than that, it's just buy large enough wire...

Comment: What loads are you planning to run off said subpanel?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do a *Load Calculation* for each of the panels in the sequence to make sure you are not overloading the service or any of the subpanels.

If you want to provision 60A, I gather your actual load is under 48A due to the 125% rule.    EV charging perhaps?

The cable will need to be enlarged due to voltage drop.  Voltage drop is calculated based on the *actual load*, not breaker trip. And 3% is *ideal* but under 5-6% is acceptable for most loads. Presuming you are running at 48A, here's what I get:

- the popular 2 AWG aluminum gives 3.70% voltage drop @ 48A.  That is good enough for North American countries whose flags are not a maple leaf.
- 1 AWG aluminum is 3.05% voltage drop (assuming 90% power factor). That is good enough for Canada too.
- 1/0 AWG aluminum is 2.62% voltage drop.
- 2/0 AWG aluminum (also popular) is 2.05% voltage drop.

Aluminum in these large sizes is proven and reliable... because large lugs are torqued down to spec and are made of aluminum anyway. Aluminum being the "universal donor" lug, playing well with both copper and aluminum wire due to favorable thermal expansion characteristics.

If the load is known and steady-state, the percentage is the electricity you are wasting.  That lets you crunch the numbers to see if the cost of larger wire would be saved by the energy saved.